# How to use AJAX to create/update radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I currently have a setup where I use a PHP script to create a list of radio buttons by loading the required information from my database. This script is in the HTML structure rather than a separate file, so it requires a page refresh to update the list.

I'd like to figure out how to delete and reload the list upon pressing a button, the ID of which is 'btnDelete' (the actual deletion of items in the database is a separate point that I won't go into here). The current code that I have will delete the list of radio buttons, but when the next line is added, nothing happens (including list deletion).

PHP (delCom.php)

```
                <?php
                    include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');
                    $query = ("SELECT comicID, comicName  FROM comic WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {
                        echo "<br><input name='comicList' id='".$row['comicID']."' type='radio' value='".$row['comicID']."'>".$row['comicName']."  </option>";
                    }
                ?>
```

JavaScript

```
function delComic()
        {
            var ajaxRequest;  

            try
            {
                // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } 
            catch (e)
            {
                // Internet Explorer Browsers
                try
                {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } 
                catch (e) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } 
                    catch (e)
                    {
                        // Something went wrong
                        alert("Your browser broke!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
                {
                    $("#loadList").remove();
                    document.getElementById("divComics").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            ajaxRequest.open("GET", "delCom.php?t=", true);
            ajaxRequest.send(null); 

        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="divComics">
            <p><u>Uploaded Comics</u></p>
            <!-- find comics in database -->
            <div id="loadList">
                <?php
                    include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');
                    $query = ("SELECT comicID, comicName  FROM comic WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' ORDER BY comicName ASC");
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {
                        echo "<br><input name='comicList' id='".$row['comicID']."' type='radio' value='".$row['comicID']."'>".$row['comicName']."  </option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input  type="button" onclick="delComic()" value="Delete Comic" name="deleteButton" id="btnDelete"/>
        </div>
```

The code creates buttons correctly when run in the HTML, but not when in a separate php file.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Updated to fix a few misnamed things and to add the new line suggested. The loadList now empties but doesn't delete itself, as it should. The current problem is that the PHP file won't output the buttons again.

Comment: You are not showing where either ajaxRequest or xmlhttp are coming from. Also, since you are tagging for jQuery, why aren't you using jQuery $.ajax?

Comment: Apologies. Edited to include the ajax request (it was a lot of catch/try stuff I presumed would be clutter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
       $username = $_GET['username'];
                    include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');
                    $query = ("SELECT comicID, comicName  FROM comic WHERE username = '$username'");
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {
                        echo "<br><input name='comicList' id='".$row['comicID']."' type='radio' value='".$row['comicID']."'>".$row['comicName']."  </option>";
                    }
                ?>

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
                {
                    document.getElementById('loadList').innerHTML="";
                    document.getElementById("divComics").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            ajaxRequest.open("GET", "delCom.php?username=MY_EXACT_NAME_I_KNOW_WORKS_HERE", true);
            ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

Comment: It's still not producing any results. Executing the php by itself outputs the radio buttons correctly, but trying to do it through the JavaScript results in the previous buttons being removed (correct) and nothing else happening (incorrect).

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. It solves half of the problem, which I admit wasn't very specific to one thing to begin with. I'll have a crack at the rest of it and if it doesn't go anywhere, I can streamline the problem into a more direct question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with an `id=comicList` and you cannot remove it `$("#comicList").remove();` in Javascript because it does not exist.  Javascript is probably stopping execution at that point, and thereby not displaying your results from PHP.

Comment: I must clarify a few things, I have noticed something since asking the question;

#comicList should be #loadList, and loadList (the div) needs to be created again within divComics in the PHP (not sure how). Apologies for the confusion. I've edited the question.

Comment: If you remove the `<div id=loadList>` then Javascript can't reference it in the following line.  Instead of remove, try `document.getElementById('loadList').innerHTML="";` this will remove the content of the div without removing the div itself.

Comment: Thanks, this wipes it as you say, but the PHP code to re-introduce the list of buttons doesn't add any. So problem partially solved, at least.

Comment: Try executing the PHP script independently to see what output it is creating by itself.  It should print to a browser window easily.  If it doesn't, then the problem is in the PHP.  If it prints, then the problem is in how Javascript is reading it.

Comment: The script printed in full, as it looks in the editor, when I ran it in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Then I suggest making your xml request a variable and placing the variable in the innerHTML

Comment: `var stuff = xmlhttp.responseText; document.getElementById('loadList').innerHTML=stuff;`

Comment: Also, why `?t=` as part of your PHP file path?

Comment: Altering it to use the variable still doesn't produce anything. I also removed ?t= from the php file path which made no difference.

Comment: ?t= is something to do with security or uniqueness. I forget specifically why.

Comment: Your PHP script requires a username as the parameter for the query.  The script when called by JS isn't loading the session.  Pass the username to the PHP `?username=$username` and access it with `$username = $_GET['username']` in the PHP.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, how do I pass it to the PHP?

Comment: no problem.  The longer I am on stackoverflow, the more I realize I don't know!  `ajaxRequest.open("GET", "delCom.php?username=$username", true);`

Comment: It's still just deleting the buttons and leaving the div blank.

Comment: When you execute the PHP file independently, how does it know what the session variable for username is?  You can only pass the variable for username to Javascript if it is embedded into a PHP script.  So, the query is looking for `username=(null)` ... try a username you know is valid.  And the PHP file should not reference the session variable for username either.

Comment: Ok I've executed the file independently, it creates the radio buttons in a blank page. This is using the default username I know is correct.